# How is a square wave generated?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, operational-amplifier, power, circuit-analysis

With regard to the picture below, it says with an AC signal as an input, the output is a square wave. I am familiar with the uses of op-amps like in differentiator, integrator, inverting and non-inverting, active filters etc. But those I can memorize their configuration. But this I could not understand.

[image: Circuit diagram including op-amp]

Comment: It's not a square wave: it's an infinitely high sine-wave clipped at the power-supply rails.

Comment: Well, that means it is a square wave, but you see what I mean?

Comment: No, it's not a square wave - the high/low plateaus are of different duration.

Comment: The corners are square but we reserve “square” for more or less desired 50% symmetry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operates like a comparator except rather than open drain or collector is a push-pull to bipolar supplies (Vcc~Vee) minus some dropout voltage.  The output is slew-rate limited to the component spec [V/us].

Remember that the (open loop) output inverts  when the inputs are not equal (ignoring Vio offset) .

### Other

This is not how you  draw a sine wave which is more like  triangular  but peaks are smooth about 25% below the apex. You often see people draw sinewaves this wave with far too much "risetime".  When we measure risetime of a pulse from 10 to 90% there is a formula to estimate the bandwidth  BW(-3dB) **BW= 0.35/Tr** (10~90%)

Here is how you can verify a hand drawn wave using 3/4 of a triangle.
[image]

Since an open loop Op Amp may saturate internally after the internal compensation , then the linear GBW does not apply and the slew rate is limited by the output stage current limit defined in the datasheet.  There may be reverse recovery times specified for overdrive unlike a good comparator IC.

Answer (score 11):

That is just used as a comparator. The sine wave is either above or below the reference and that is the result of the comparison.

Comment: Okay , now I got it. Thank you 

Comment: Is that all?....

Answer (score 6):

If you consider the inverting mode amplifier with which you are familiar you should be able to spot:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flFp92.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An inverting amplifier. If R<sub>f</sub> is omitted, then R<sub>f</sub> = ∞ and the gain becomes the open-loop gain of the op-amp.*

1. The signal is applied to the inverting input so it's an inverting amplifier.
2. R2 and R3 provide a reference voltage for the non-inverting input. R2 should, presumably, be connected to +V<sub>S</sub>.
3. There is no negative feedback resistor or, to put it another way, R<sub>f</sub> = ∞ so the gain is "infinite".

As soon as V<sub>IN-</sub> exceeds V<sub>IN+</sub> the output will swing to the negative rail. When the situation is reversed the output will swing to the positive rail.

Comment: no, that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Okay you mean of the op-amp. Ok

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: what about those "do not use opAmps as comparators" thing?

Comment: @muyustan: Good! You were [paying attention](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471648/lm393-comparator-how-to-use/471651#471651).

Comment: @Transistor just suppose, **I *have to* use opAmps as comparators, since I am not allowed to use a comparator IC** , using an LM324 or LM741(I know, I know it is ancient but if it fits here, I want to make use of it) with +9v and GND as rails, for example, for an application which does not require fast switching between + and - rails, it will do the job at least, right?

Comment: @muyustan the LM324 would be a better choice. LM741 has minimum recommended supply voltage of 10V. Its inputs need to stay 2V away from the supply and ground for correct operation, and the output also only gets to within 1~2V of the supply rails (that's a big loss when running from 9V!).

Comment: @BruceAbbott thanks!